# Deploying Gatein in EAP-6

Tags: deployment, jboss-eap-6, gatein

I need to deploy Gatein in EAP 6.

For this i have followed the instructions given in
https://github.com/gatein/gatein-portal

As per the instructions given in the above website,the EAP version supported is EAP-6.3.0.Alpha1

Now the downloads page of Jboss EAP does not show EAP 6.3.0.Alpha1 but shows EAP 6.3.0.Alpha.

I downloaded EAP 6.3.0.Beta and tried deploying gatein in EAP 6.3.0.Beta.

I also unzipped the repository folder to .m2/repository.

Now when I try to run with the following command,

mvn install -DskipTests -Dservers.dir=D:/Softwares/SERVERS_DIR -Dgatein.dev=eap630

I get the following error,
......

[INFO] GateIn JBoss AS-based packaging (Wildfly / EAP) ... SUCCESS [0.070s]

[INFO] GateIn - Portlet Container (JBoss AS-based Extension)  FAILURE [17.446s]

[INFO] GateIn - Portlet Container (JBoss AS-based Extension Modules)  SKIPPED

[INFO] GateIn package for JBoss AS-based (Wildfly / EAP) . SKIPPED

[INFO] TestSuite for GateIn .............................. SKIPPED

[INFO] Selenium Sniff Test for GateIn .................... SKIPPED

[INFO] GateIn Portal Examples - WebUI based samples ...... SKIPPED

[INFO] HTMLUnit Tests for GateIn ......................... SKIPPED

[INFO] Selenium UI Tests for GateIn ...................... SKIPPED

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Total time: 4:27.144s

[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jun 26 14:32:55 IST 2014

[INFO] Final Memory: 121M/247M

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project jboss-integration-extension: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.gatein.portal:jboss-integration-

extension:jar:3.9.0.Alpha01-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [org.jboss.as:jboss-as-controller:jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4 (compile), org.jbo

ss.as:jboss-as-server:jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4 (compile), org.jboss.as:jboss-as-ee:jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4 (compile), org.jboss.as:jboss-as-web:jar:7

.4.0.Final-redhat-4 (compile), org.jboss.as:jboss-as-weld:jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4 (compile), org.jboss:jboss-vfs:jar:3.1.0.Final (compile), org.exopl

atform.kernel:exo.kernel.container:jar:2.5.0-GA (compile), org.gatein.portal:exo.portal.webui.portal:jar:3.9.0.Alpha01-SNAPSHOT (compile), org.gatein.

wci:wci-jboss7:jar:2.4.2.Final (compile), org.gatein.integration:extension-component:jar:3.9.0.Alpha01-SNAPSHOT (compile), org.gatein.wsrp:wsrp-integr

ation-api:jar:2.3.2.Final (provided), org.gatein.cdi:gatein-cdi-contexts:jar:3.9.0.Alpha01-SNAPSHOT (compile), org.jboss.portletbridge:portletbridge-i

mpl:jar:3.3.2.Final (compile), junit:junit:jar:4.10 (test), org.jboss.as:jboss-as-subsystem-test-framework:jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4 (compile), org.slf

4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.5 (test), org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.5 (test), commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1 (test), org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:2.

3.0 (test), org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.0-GA (test)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.jboss.sasl:jboss-sasl:jar:1.0.3.Final-redhat-1:

Could not transfer artifact org.jboss:jboss-parent:pom:9-redhat-1 from/to jboss-product-repository (http://download.lab.bos.redhat.com/brewroot/repos/

jb-eap-6-rhel-6-build/latest/maven/): download.lab.bos.redhat.com: Unknown host download.lab.bos.redhat.com -> [Help 1]

[ERROR]

[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

[ERROR]

[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

[[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command

[ERROR]   mvn  -rf :jboss-integration-extension

Let me know how to resolve the same.

Also, I would like to make this work in a GA version of EAP (EAP-6.2.0.GA) Let me know ho to make this work.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you update your settings file to use some specific repository? Mentionning this url http://download.lab.bos.redhat.com/brewroot/repos/

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the JBoss central Nexus repository url if mvn complains about some missing artifacts.
This can be done by declaring two profiles for JBoss and eXo public repositories either into your `$Home/.me/settings.xml` file or under your `pom.xml` file. (I suggest the former):

```
<settings>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>jboss-public-repository</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
          <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>
          <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
          <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>
          <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>

    <profile>
      <id>exo-public-repository</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>exo-public-repository-group</id>
          <name>eXo Public Maven Repository Group</name>
          <url>http://repository.exoplatform.org/content/groups/public</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>exo-public-repository-group</id>
          <name>eXo Public Maven Repository Group</name>
          <url>http://repository.exoplatform.org/content/groups/public</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</settings>
```

Then while executing the build, you should activate those profiles as follows:

```
mvn install -DskipTests -Dservers.dir=D:/Softwares/SERVERS_DIR -Dgatein.dev=eap630 -Pjboss-public-repository -Pexo-public-repository
```

Answer (score 0):

I can build gatein 3.8.9.Alpha03-SNAPSHOT with JBoss EAP 6.3.0 after downloading its maven-repository, unzip it to the local repository and update as follows.

```
--- a/packaging/jboss/pom.xml
+++ b/packaging/jboss/pom.xml
@@ -12,7 +12,7 @@
   <name>GateIn JBoss AS-based packaging (Wildfly / EAP)</name>

   <properties>
-    <version.jboss.as>7.4.0.Final-redhat-4</version.jboss.as>
+    <version.jboss.as>7.4.0.Final-redhat-19</version.jboss.as>
     <package.filename>package.xml</package.filename>
```